# TCP server not recognizing switched off IOT device

Tags: go, networking, tcp

I've built a server that is connected to multiple IOT devices. They communicate solely over TCP and use a vendor-specific protocol.

My server is listening to the TCP connection and whenever I receive an `EOF` I close the connection and clean everything up.

This works fine when I use a tool like "Packet Sender". As soon as I click the "Close" button my server recognizes that the client closed the connection and then does the clean up.

The problem occurs when I use the real machines that are connected over the telephone network (SIM cards). When I switch them off - literally nothing happens in my server. Even worse: I can still **write** to those devices without any problems (except the device is offline)!

From my perspective we should at least know that the connection is closed by the client if we try to write to it?

Why is there such a difference in the behavior between my tool "Packet Sender" and the real machines?

Also: how can I solve the problem of getting informed right away when a machine is turned off?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems the device is not properly closing the TCP connection on shutdown. Even if it did, crashes/disconnects/etc... can have the same effect. You need to set [TCP keep alive](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#TCPConn.SetKeepAlive) to periodically ping the remote host. Even then, it won't be immediate, it'll depend on the keep alive period.

Comment: This is how TCP works, and all networks services need to take this into account. If the device protocol has no heartbeat or keepalive of any sort, then you're left with tcp keepalive.

Comment: @JimB But shouldn't it fail when I write to connection?

Comment: No, how would it detect that if the connection is not closed properly? (think about the TCP protocol here).  After you write you _may_ get an RST or ICMP response at some point indicating the connection is broken, but you have to wait for that packet to arrive. Until then you can only keep sending or wait for a response of some sort.